# Why does this IF formula not work?

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

Can someone help me with the below.. It seems to find everything without a problem but it will not print the report.Cells(i, 1) = hr.Cells(j, 3) portion. At one point it did somehow get it to print but it just kept overwriting the first cell.

```
Dim hr As Worksheet
Dim report As Worksheet
Sub populateMetaData()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Set report = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set hr = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("HR_Report")

For j = 2 To hr.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 2 To report.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        If hr.Cells(j, 10) = "AWM TECH & OPS" Then
            report.Cells(i, 1) = hr.Cells(j, 3)

        End If

    Next i
Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: Is the cell being tested `hr.Cells(j,10)` definitely `AWM TECH & OPS` Same all upper caps, no spaces hanging out at the end, etc?

Comment: yeah its a full copy paste

Comment: I am going to assume it's a values thing.`report.Cells(i, 1).value = hr.Cells(j, 3).value`

Comment: Didnt work, still just skips over the If forumula. Step by step if hits the two For statements and jumps right to next j

Comment: Toss a breakpoint on the if statement and then hover over the `hr.cells(j,10)` when it hits that line. Check the values. Something is off there.

Comment: You may need the `hr.Cells(j, 10).value` as well

Comment: Your response to @Davesexcel is unclear to me. It sounds almost like you're saying that when you step through it, it never even gets to the `If` line. And unless it was a typo in your answer, it also never gets to the `Next i`. If that's the case, when you're on the `For i` line, I would hover the mouse over `report.UsedRange.Rows.Count` and see what that value is. If it's 2 or less, that could be causing the issue.

Comment: Looks like it was a bad loop that skipped the IF statement.

     i = 2
    For j = 2 To hr.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        If hr.Cells(j, 10) = "AM" Then
        report.Cells(i, 1) = hr.Cells(j, 3)

    i = i + 1
        End If

     Next j



    End Sub

Comment: Yeah i dont know what i was thinking with this i=i+1 is what i needed. thanks for the help!